# JavaScript regex using a character twice

Tags: javascript, regex, hash, match

So I'm using regex to grab information from a string, the issue is I need to both start up and stop at a `/` in the string.

Here's an example

```
var regexp = /\/(.*?)=(.*?)\//g;
    var url_hash = "/s=lorem+ipsum/p=2/";
    var match;
    var result = {};
    while ((match = regexp.exec(url_hash)) != null) {
     result[match[1]] = match[2];
  }
```

I can grab `result['s']` without issue, but grabbing `result['p']` becomes problematic, because the ending `/` for `result['s']` is the same as the starting `/` for `result['p']`. If I changed the string to `/s=lorem+ipsum//p=2/` it works perfectly, but of course that's hideous. So how can I fix this so that it both ends and starts up at the `/`? I'm stuck, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you use `/\/(.*?)=(.*?)/g;` as the regex?

Comment: I don't know but it won't grab the `result['p']` unless I add the extra slash. go ahead and test it.

Comment: `(.*?)` will not end where Ian wants it to. Instead result['s'] will contain `=lorem+ipsum/p=2/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
/\/([^/=]+)=([^/]+)/
```

**Code:**

```
var regexp = /\/([^/=]+)=([^/]+)/g;
var url_hash = "/#!/s=lorem+ipsum/p=2/";
var match;
var result = {};
while ((match = regexp.exec(url_hash)) != null) {
   result[match[1]] = match[2];
   document.writeln(match[1] + ' = ' + match[2] + '<br>');
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
s = lorem+ipsum
p = 2
```

[`Online demo of the code`](http://jsfiddle.net/FYtSy/1/)

Comment: Thank you, exactly the solution I was looking for. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you just `split` it?

```
var result = {};
var url = "/#!/s=lorem+ipsum/p=2/".slice(4, -1).split('/');

for (i in url) {
  var value = url[i].split('=');
  result[value[0]] = value[1];
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can determine the look-ahead set for part after the `=` yourself instead of adding it to the regular expression. The look-ahead set is "everything but a forward slash".

```
var regexp = /\/(\w+)=([^/]+)/g;
```

Btw, I'm assuming that the part before the `=` is word-like (i.e. alphanumeric)